# SharePoint 2019 is so slow after migrating from SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server

Good afternoon,

I am about to migrate my SharePoint sites from SharePoint 2016 to SharePoint 2019.

I have just finished setting up my SharePoint 2019 server but it is so much slower than 2016.

This issue could be my fault: I decided to split my 4 sub sites into 4 sites. So instead of having:
http://sps16/sites/company1/default.aspx
http://sps16/sites/company2/default.aspx
http://sps16/sites/company3/default.aspx
http://sps16/sites/company4/default.aspx

I have now:
http://sps19:3000/default.aspx
http://sps19:3010/default.aspx
http://sps19:3020/default.aspx
http://sps19:3030/default.aspx

So 4 web applications instead of 1.

Is it the problem?

Right now it is not usable as it is so slow (and I have not started the migration yet).

Thanks

Christophe

Answer (score 1):

Splitting sub sites into sites won't be cause of slowness... the reason could be something else. I feel this could be the issue with database and network connectivity, please check your network connectivity between from SharePoint WFE server to database server.

I am not sure how your data base is structured... as a best practice we should have AG(availability group) configured in database along with at least two listeners(cluster).

So, in order to deal with this kind of situation, we need to verify the below :

- Check the ULS logs, there we could see exactly what is wrong.
- Make sure, all the four content database or database which is
  connected to the above sites are joined to listner 1 db in the AG
  group set up (in db server)
- If you have used a single content db for all the sites, try to have one to one content db for each sites.

Comment: I could not find a reason why it was so slow so I decided to try reconfiguring SharePoint 2019 the same way I did with 2016: One web app and four subsites. It is now as fast as 2016 or even faster. I am not going to waste any more time trying to debug the reason and stay with this approach/design

Answer (score 0):

My answer presumes that IIS is not the bottleneck.
I have had to do the below in multiple prior migrations on prem, like you.

On-Prem: every Site Collection *should* have its own Content DB - This is best practice. 
Ergo:  ***Definitely*** *every* Web Application should have separate content databases.

You need to pre-create new content databases for each new site collection.
Your powershell script would look like this:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
#Variables for Database server and Content Database Name
$DatabaseServerName = "YOUR-DB-SERVER"
$DatabaseName = "Hosting_ContentDB_001"
$WebAppName = "SharePoint Hosting"
New-SPContentDatabase -Name $DatabaseName -DatabaseServer $DatabaseServerName -WebApplication $WebAppName -MaxSiteCount 100 -WarningSiteCount 80
```

If, you already have done this, or if you do the above and you still have that latency, your SQL server is under powered.

Comment: Maybe my server was under powered. Using one web app fixed the issue.